# Map a key to run formatter in Vim

Tags: vim

I have this in my `.vimrc`

```
set formatprg=astyle
```

I can press `gggqG` to format the whole file just fine,.

Now I'd like to map a hotkey to do this, eg `<F10>`, but `gggqG` is not a command I type in Vim command line, so I don't know how to map this to a key. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_map_keys_in_vim):

```
map <F10> gggqG
```

Comment: If you want to be able to do this in insert mode you might try adding an `imap <F10> magggqG\`ai`. Which jumps you out of insert mode, marks your current position, reformats everything, jumps back to your mark and puts you back into insert mode.

Comment: It's always good practice to use `nnoremap` unless you consciously need to use recursion. (Or `inoremap` if using the above suggestion). It doesn't make any difference in this case, but it's still worth bearing in mind.

Comment: The imap (or inoremap, which I suggest too) is missing an <esc>, `inoremap <F10> <esq>magggqG`ai`, otherwise it will simply type "magggqG`ai" in insert mode.